# How this embed images works in JS file opened with notepad?

Tags: javascript

I downloaded some JS chess game to modify it and made a game based on chess.

I get so confused cause using the notepad I found this lines:

```
const piecesCharacters = {
0: '♙',
1: '♘',
2: '♗',
3: '♖',
4: '♕',
5: '♔'};
```

WTF is that. This is not notepad coding! There is not directory of the images? Not URL? The images are embed to the js file? How can i modify that images?

Comment: those are unicode characters.. that gets rendered depending on which one was used... for example what you see as ♙ is %u2659. But those are still just strings not strictly pictures

Comment: These aren't images, these are unicode character kinda like smileys, you can see them [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/chess-symbols/) for example

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Did not know that unicode reach the chess pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (the main standard for encoding text for computers) has a wide variety of symbols representing numbers and letters from a wide variety of languages, mathematical symbols, other symbols and icons, and even emoji.

Those examples are [chess symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode) from character block 0x1FA00.